# Error in data[[y_orig_val]] : subscript out of bounds - when running train() from caret package

Tags: r, r-caret, knn

I have this issue where I am trying to run a KNN model on training data, but it shows me the error: `"Error in data[[y_orig_val]]` : subscript out of bounds" when running the train function.

First I imported and split it into train and test sets:

```
library(xts)
data1 = xts(x=data[,-1],order.by= as.POSIXct(data$Date))
set.seed(1)
data_split1 <- initial_split(data1, prop = 0.7)
train1 <- training(data_split1)
test1 <- testing(data_split1)
```

Then I made a blueprint to put into the train() function, where I normalized the predictors without one:

```
blueprint <- recipe(SNPclose ~., data = train1) %>% 
  step_normalize(all_predictors(), -longtermvsshortterm)
```

I created this for the resampling method, using 5 fold crossvalidation:

```
cv1 <- trainControl(
  method = "cv", 
  number = 5,
  summaryFunction = defaultSummary
  )
```

Made the hypergrid:
hyper_grid <- expand.grid(k = seq(2, 25, by = 1))

But when I try to fit the KNN model, I get the error:

```
# fit knn model
knn_grid <- train(
  blueprint, 
  data = train1, 
  method = "knn", 
  trControl = cv1, 
  tuneGrid = hyper_grid,
  metric = "RMSE"
)
```

= Error in data[[y_orig_val]] : subscript out of bounds

Anybody that have any ideas to where it goes wrong? I simply just follow the book"Hands-On Machine Learning with R" to fit the model  (and adjust the parameters to fit my data).

Best regards.

Comment: If only the problem was reproducible on my machine... I am sure I could help you.

Comment: Hi, I can send the script and data if you want to?